# Ninject. Binding all interfaces to the same class in singleton scope

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, singleton, ninject

I want one class to be both an object, which provides information about the backend, and a class, which a backend informs when servers goes down (e.g. ZooKeeper or WCF).
The problem is when I bind the same class to two different interfaces in in singleton scope, Ninject creates either two instances or throws an error, depending on how I do it.

*The following example must print the same Guid and all interfaces must be bound.*

Example:

**Program.cs**

```
using System;
using Ninject;
using Ninject.Modules;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    static class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IKernel kernel = new StandardKernel();
            kernel.Load(new INinjectModule[] { new Bindings() });
            Console.WriteLine("First interface");
            var i1 = kernel.Get<IState>();
            i1.Inform();
            Console.WriteLine("Second interface");
            var i2 = kernel.Get<IListener>();
            i2.Send();
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

**IListener.cs**

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    public interface IListener
    {
        void Send();
    }
}
```

**IState.cs**

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    public interface IState
    {
        void Inform();
    }
}
```

**StateClass.cs**
using System;

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    public class StateClass : IState, IListener
    {
        private readonly String _seed;
        public StateClass()
        {
            _seed = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        }
        public void Send()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(_seed);
        }

        public void Inform()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(_seed);
        }
    }
}
```

**Bindings.cs - Version 1** In this example everything works, if the code is commented. The problem is I dont know in advance if a class impelments **IState** interface it will also **IListener** interface:

```
using Ninject.Modules;
using Ninject.Extensions.Conventions;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Bindings : NinjectModule
    {
        public override void Load()
        {
            Kernel.Bind(x => x
                .FromAssemblyContaining<IState>()
                .SelectAllClasses()
                .InheritedFrom<IState>()
                .BindAllInterfaces()
                .Configure(y => y.InSingletonScope()));
            //uncomment the following binding to see an exception
            //problem is we dont know this in advance
            //Kernel.Bind(x => x
            //    .FromAssemblyContaining<IListener>()
            //    .SelectAllClasses()
            //    .InheritedFrom<IListener>()
            //    .BindAllInterfaces()
            //    .Configure(y => y.InSingletonScope()));
        }
    }
}
```

**Bindings.cs - Version 2** - no exception, but Application prints different Guids:

```
using Ninject.Modules;
using Ninject.Extensions.Conventions;

    namespace ConsoleApplication1
    {
        class Bindings : NinjectModule
        {
            public override void Load()
            {
                Kernel.Bind<IListener>().To<StateClass>().InSingletonScope();
                Kernel.Bind<IState>().To<StateClass>().InSingletonScope();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

So I think in your module you're going to have to tell Ninject that both interfaces are using the same object. if you don't, Ninject will always assume that each interface has its own singleton.

```
class Bindings : NinjectModule
{
    public override void Load()
    {
        Kernel.Bind<StateClass>().ToSelf().InSingletonScope();
        Kernel.Bind<IListener>().ToMethod(ctx => ctx.Kernel.Get<StateClass>());
        Kernel.Bind<IState>().ToMethod(ctx => ctx.Kernel.Get<StateClass>());
    }
}
```

Comment: How about Ninject.Conventions part, when one aims for plugin infrastructure?

Comment: I think that the conventions will always treat each interface separately; in other words, create a singleton for each interface, regardless of what implements it. if you truly want it to be pluggable, I think you need another layer of abstraction - create a separate broker class (as a singleton) that will hold whatever data that both the IListener implementation and the IState implementation need to access (the Guid in this example). that way the framework is agnostic of the implementation of the interfaces.